# spring MVC model attributes in jsp page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring, jsp

When I access simple model data like the username using : ${username} everything seems to be fine.  But when I try to use ${userdata.uname} I get an error like :

```
Could not find property uname in class com.mydom.datahandling.userdata
```

userdata is java class I add to the ModelAndView

```
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("page37");
   mav.addObject("sessionID",ID);
   mav.addObject("userdata",p37userdata);
```

What do I need to do differently ?  This seems to be happening whenever I try to use something other than a primitive type or String.  I obviously need a bit more education.  Do I need to serialize p37userdata?

userdata is

```
   public class userdata{
   public String uname;
       public String otherstuff;
   }
```

Comment: what is p37userdata?  Does it contain a "uname" property?

Comment: Crud - Do I need getters for the attributes of the userdata for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you reference from your EL in your JSP should be java beans (or a map).  According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) (the source of all truth) A bean has the following properties:

> They are serializable, have a 0-argument constructor, and allow access
>   to properties using getter and setter methods.

So you should probably add getters and setters to your userdata class.